# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePadCanvasView'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> Plugin used: **Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePade.Forms (3.0.0)**

Working fine in iOS but in Android it throws ObjectDisposedException

```
try
{
    Stream img = await padView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignaturePad.Forms.SignatureImageFormat.Png);//.GetImage(ImageFormatType.Png);
    ImageSource imgSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => img);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    long pos = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? 0 : img.Position;

    img.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] imageArray = memoryStream.ToArray();

    ProfileViewModel.SignatureBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
    DigitalSignaturePageViewModel.SignatureBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
    img.Position = pos;
    GetSignature.Invoke(this, imgSource);

}
catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Is the inner exception details referencing the first line in the try block?

Comment: Yes, it throws exception on first line:     Stream img = await padView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignaturePad.Forms.SignatureImageFormat.Png);//.GetImage(ImageFormatType.Png); @Csharpest

Comment: how do u initialize padView?

Comment: using xaml like this: <acr:SignaturePadView x:Name="padView" HeightRequest="160" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White" ClearText="{Localize:ETranslate Clear}" ClearTextColor="Red" SignatureLineColor="#024b6f" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="1,1,1,1"
                                StrokeColor="Black" CaptionText="{Localize:ETranslate SignHere}" /> @Csharpest

Comment: @Divyesh_008,I find one sample about using SignaturePadView,https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad and using `var bitmap = await signatureView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png, Color.Black, Color.White, 1f)` have no issue.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I have tried what you are suggesting but still I got the same problem

Answer (score -2):

I have used padView getting same exception. I have cleared SignaturePad after all work done with image. I have done like padView?.Clear(); may be helpful.